# Let $A = \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$ and $B=\{3, 6, 9\}$. Find each of the following: (i) $A \cup B$ (ii) $A \cap B$ (iii) $A − B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$ and $B=\{3, 6, 9\}$. Find each of the following:

(i) $A \cup B$

(ii) $A \cap B$

(iii) $A − B$

I am doing a test today which I must prove this kind but honestly speaking I faced trouble with this I really want guide here.

Comment: MSE is not a homework solution service :|

Comment: If $B=\{3,6,9\}$, then this is just a straightforward application of the definitions, so please, share your attempts in order for others to better understand what you do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bite and try to teach you the question rather than give just the answers.

You have that $A = \{1,3,5,7,9\}$ and $B = \{3,6,9\}$.

(i) We want to find $A \cup B$. This is the *union* of sets $A$ and $B$. So $A \cup B$ is the set with all of the elements from $A$ and all of the elements from $B$ (we obviously do not need to write duplicates twice). So $A \cup B =\{1,3,5,6,7,9\}$.

(ii) We want to find $A \cap B$. This is the *intersection* of sets $A$ and $B$. So $A \cap B$ is the set with elements that are simultaneously in $A$ and $B$. The only elements that are in both $A$ and $B$ are $3$ and $9$. So $A \cap B = \{3, 9\}$.

(iii) We want to find $A - B$. Sometimes this is written as $A \setminus B$. That is, we want to take away the set $B$ from the set $A$. So $A-B$ is just the set $A$ without the elements $3, 6, 9$ (note that $6$ isn't actually in $A$ anyway). So $A-B = \{1,5,7\}$.

Answer (score 0):

These are basic definitions and you should know them as well as you know english.

But here goes..

$A = \{1,3,5,7,9\}; B = \{3,6,9\}$

$\cup = $ "union" means to the set that contains the combined elements of both sets.

$A \cup B = \{1,3,5,6,7,9\}$ because 1,3,5,6,7,9 are all the elements in the two sets.

$\cap = $ "intesection" means the set that contains the elements that are in both sets.

$A \cap B = \{3,9\}$ because 3, and 9 are all the elements that are in both sets.

$- = $ "minus"  means all the elements in the first set that are not in the second set.

$A - B =\{1,5,7\}$ because 1,5,7 are the elements in A that are not also in B. 3 and 9 are also in A but they are also in B so we have to remove them.

These should be head slappingly obvious.